# list(REMOVE_ITEM) not working in cmake

Tags: cmake

Following is a part of my CMakeLists.txt file.

```
file(GLOB SOURCES "xyz/*.cpp")
message("${SOURCES}")
list(REMOVE_ITEM SOURCES "src1.cpp")
message("${SOURCES}")
```

Here in file `"xyz/*.cpp"` is a relative path.
Content of `${SOURCES}` is the same before and after `REMOVE_ITEM`.

Why is `list(REMOVE_ITEM)` not working in my case? Any help would be invaluable.

Comment: Is your `SOURCES` list has item exactly same as `src1.cpp`?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I didnt understand your question.

Comment: As @kristian has answered, your `SOURCES` list doesn't contain item `src1.cpp` (exactly). That is why `list(REMOVE_ITEM)` does nothing in your case.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I got a solution for your problem. The idea behind my solution is, to get the full path of the special cpp file, because I saw, that the command `file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")` gives me a list of full paths. After getting the full path of the special file, I could do a remove from the list. Here is a small example

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(list_remove_item_ex)

file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")
# this is the file I want to exclude / remove from the list
get_filename_component(full_path_test_cpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/test.cpp ABSOLUTE)
message("${full_path_test_cpp}")

list(REMOVE_ITEM SOURCES "${full_path_test_cpp}")
message("${SOURCES}")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works like a charm. If you feel the question is good enough please upvote :)

Comment: Path contained in variable [CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.html) is already *absolute*. So you may use filename `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/test.cpp` with `list(REMOVE_ITEM)` without preprocessing by `get_filename_component`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev it works like a charm. Ill edit the answer.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to accepted answer you can use the following function to filter lists using regexp:

```
# Filter values through regex
#   filter_regex({INCLUDE | EXCLUDE} <regex> <listname> [items...])
#   Element will included into result list if
#     INCLUDE is specified and it matches with regex or
#     EXCLUDE is specified and it doesn't match with regex.
# Example:
#   filter_regex(INCLUDE "(a|c)" LISTOUT a b c d) => a c
#   filter_regex(EXCLUDE "(a|c)" LISTOUT a b c d) => b d
function(filter_regex _action _regex _listname)
    # check an action
    if("${_action}" STREQUAL "INCLUDE")
        set(has_include TRUE)
    elseif("${_action}" STREQUAL "EXCLUDE")
        set(has_include FALSE)
    else()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Incorrect value for ACTION: ${_action}")
    endif()

    set(${_listname})
    foreach(element ${ARGN})
        string(REGEX MATCH ${_regex} result ${element})
        if(result)
            if(has_include)
                list(APPEND ${_listname} ${element})
            endif()
        else()
            if(NOT has_include)
                list(APPEND ${_listname} ${element})
            endif()
        endif()
    endforeach()

    # put result in parent scope variable
    set(${_listname} ${${_listname}} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
```

For example in question it could look as the following:

```
file(GLOB SOURCES "xyz/*.cpp")
message("${SOURCES}")
filter_regex(EXCLUDE "src1\\.cpp" SOURCES ${SOURCES})
message("${SOURCES}")
```

(Because regexp is used then `.` is replaced with `\\.`)